# Canonical basis and perverse coherent sheaves on the nilpotent cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, coherent-sheaves, perverse-sheaves, canonical-bases

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911068) of Ostrik, he introduced a canonical basis of $K^{G\times {\mathbb C}^*}(\mathcal N)$, where $\mathcal N$ is the nilpotent cone for the group $G$. Question: does this canonical basis coincide with the basis formed by irreducible $G\times {\mathbb C}^*$-equivariant perverse coherent sheaves on the nilpotent cone, which are described, for example, in Theorem 1.4 in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7346) by Achar?